# How can I avoid disk write times when writing to temporary files?

Tags: file, file-io, filesystems, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

Suppose I have some executable which I cannot modify, `exec.exe`, which takes a file name as an argument and performs some operation on the data within that file.

I am writing a program which generates some file for `exec.exe` to use, but I am only interested in the output of `exec.exe`.

It seems that I must write to some temporary file, and call `exec.exe` on that file - meaning that I must write and read from some file on disk. Is there a way to avoid this, and keep the file in memory somehow?

I am writing a cross-platform application for Linux, OSX and Windows, using .NET/Mono.

Comment: You need a RAMdisk. You should specify your operating system (Windows at a guess from the .exe); I believe there is nothing built-in but RAMdisk products are available

Comment: @AndrewMcGuinness is right. Alternatively, if you can make exec.exe read from stdin, you could pipe data from your application to it by writing to stdout,.

Comment: I am writing for Windows, OSX and Linux, I've edited my post to show this.

I can't edit `exec.exe`.

Comment: I was not suggesting to modify the program, but many command line programs can take their input from a file or from stdin. If that's not the case, a ramdisk is your best bet.

Comment: I see. I don't have that option unfortunately.